# Pure CSS modal (::target) with angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My first question here :)

I'm porting my site to Angular (I'm new to it) and wondering if I'd be able to keep my pure CSS modal dialogue box while using ui-router. In HTML it looks like this:

```
<a id="footerMail" href="#openContact"></a>
<div id="openContact" class="modal">
<div class="modal__container">
    <a href="#close" title="Close" class="modal__close">X</a>
    <form class="contact-form" action="/" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
    </form>
</div>
```

It uses `::target` on openContact id. But when I'm trying to do that while using ui-router it, obviously, doesn't allow that path to happen since it's not defined as a state. How should I define it since I don't want to redirect to a new URL just open a modal that is overlay of the current state? My $stateProvider looks like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/site/editor");
$stateProvider
  .state('site', {
     url: "/site",
     abstract: true,
     templateUrl: "partials/site.html",
     controller: 'MainController as ctrl'
  })
  .state('site.director', {
     url: "/director",
     templateUrl: "partials/gallery.html",
     controller: 'GalleryController'
  })
  .state('site.editor', {
     url: "/editor",
     templateUrl: "partials/gallery.html",
     controller: 'GalleryController'
  });
});
```

The link and modal code would ideally fire from the main 'site" state since it's common for all subpages. Or maybe that's too much work and I should rewrite it and not use CSS approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your modal is always present you should just be able to use ng-show to control when it's displayed.

I typically have an application level control that I have on my body tag and have it created with something like ng-controller=AppController as app. If you had a property of this controller named showModal that you initialize as false you can have your modal created outside of the div for your ui-view and have ng-show="app.ShowModal" then in any link where you want to display the modal in the function you call from its ng-click set app.showModal to false.

There are a lot of good approaches for modals in Angular though. I've been using mdDialog from Angular Material and this one: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm is also good. I've used the one from UI Bootstrap as well.